# Frontispiece for PhD thesis in a Portuguese university

Tags: titles, frontespizio

I am writing the frontispiece for my PhD thesis (in English), which must be composed according to this layout in my university in Portugal:

http://npgfc.tecnico.ulisboa.pt/files/sites/29/Capa-tese-doutoramento-vers%C3%A3o-provis%C3%B3ria1.pdf

I wonder if the `frontespizio` package (or alternative packages) is adequate for that, in particular given the constraints that I list below. I am Italian so I am OK with reading its documentation.

Layout requirements:

- logo placed in the upper-left corner of the page;
- no horizontal lines should be present in the frontispiece: I believe the command `\norules` takes care of this;
- then a few text fields appear in the following order (always centered horizontally):
- first the name of the university (spans two lines) without any prefix: the command `\Istituzione` seems to do this just fine;
- then an optional accompanying image to the thesis title;
- then the thesis title;
- then the candidate name (without any prefix such as "Candidato:");
- then "Supervisor:" with his/her full name;
- then "Co-Supervisor:" with his/her full name;
- then this statement: "Thesis specifically prepared to obtain the PhD Degree in Electrical and Computer Engineering";
- then the statement: "Draft";
- lastly, date in the format "Month Year", e.g., "October 2015".

Many thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I'm sorry, but I don't think that `frontespizio` is adequate to the job: too many changes are necessary.

Comment: I see, thank you for the quick answer! Any other suggested package for my purpose? I'm looking at `titling`, `titlepages`, or producing the PDF with an external word processor and then including it with `pdfpages`.

Comment: The simplest way is to produce it as a single PDF page to be included with `pdfpages`. But with `geometry` it's not difficult to set up a special page. There's a recent answer by Harish Kumar that deals with a similar problem. Building the title page itself is not a big deal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more or less what you can do:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[pass]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\newgeometry{
  left=3cm,right=3cm,
  top=1cm,bottom=3cm
}

\begin{titlepage}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\includegraphics[width=5cm,height=2cm]{example-image}%
\hspace*{\fill}\hspace*{-1cm}%
\makebox[1cm][l]{\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=2cm]{example-image}}

\begingroup
\centering

\LARGE
UNIVERSIDADE DE LISBOA\\
INSTITUTO SUPERIOR T\'ECNICO

\bigskip

\large

\mbox{\phantom{A}}\\ % or the other institution
\mbox{\phantom{B}}

\vspace{3cm}

T\'itulo da Tese

\vspace{3cm}

Nome do autor

\vspace{3cm}
\endgroup

\large

Orientador: Dotor O. Rientador

\bigskip

Co-Orientador: Dotor C. O. Orientador

\vspace{3cm}

\centering

Tese especialmente elaborata para obten\c{c}\~{a}o do Grau de Dotor em\\
Tipograf\'ia

\vspace{3cm}

Tese Provis\'oria

\vspace{\fill}

2015

\end{titlepage}

\restoregeometry

\chapter{X}

\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

If you already use `geometry` for the document, don't set the `pass` option. Adjust to suit. You can check that the rest of the document is typeset under the standard setting of the `book` class.

[image]

Comment: That looks very much like the official layout! I'm finalizing it by customizing some minor details, like distances and words that should appear in bold, and basically that's done. Thanks again.